# Empty element in C character array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm going through some source code for initializing a webcam in Linux and came across the following puzzling lines of code:

```
struct stat st;
char devName[15] = {0, };

sprintf(devName, "/dev/video%d", deviceIndex);
```

it appears that the leading zero doesn't do anything:

```
printf("%s", devName);
```

returns /dev/video13 where 13 was the deviceIndex.

What does the leading zero do? What does it mean if there's nothing after the comma? `{0, };`

Comment: It is generally written `char devName[15] = {0};` Initialization has many purposes, one particularly important one for character arrays to be used as string values is to guarantee that a *nul-terminating* character exists -- in the event the remainder of the code fails to properly terminate the string.

Comment: The rule for C is that if the array is longer than the initializer, the rest is filled with zeros.  So {0} is an idiom  to fill the whole array with zero. Additionally, the last element of the list is allowed to have a comma after it. This is a maintenance help. If you have a long list with one entry per, each with the trailing comma, you can always add a new entry the same way, not go back and add a comma first.

Comment: @Gene: Not sure what you mena with "maintenance help". But allowing a trailing comma definitively simplifies automatic code generation.

Comment: you don't even need to initialize `devName` because it is gonna to be overwritten anyway.

Comment: @milevyo Or, _overrun_ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the array `devName` would be filled with `0`s.

Array with missing values will be initialized to 0:

```
int devName[10] = { 1, 2 }; // initialize to 1,2,0,0,0...
```

This goes for all types of arrays, be it `char` or `int`.

---

First you use `sprintf(devName, "/dev/video%d", deviceIndex);`. This overwrites the array `devName` with the string `/dev/video13`, assuming `deviceIndex = 13`. But those are only 12 `char`. The rest `3` still have `\0`.

The array of yours is a `char` array. A char with ascii value `0` is the `NUL` `\0` character. So when you print the array, it prints till the last `\0`, just like strings do.

Comment: Why don't those 0s show up when I print the array? Or am I confusing integer zeros with character zeros?

Comment: `sprintf` fills the variable `devName` with the new data, `"/dev/video13"`, overwriting all the zeros that were there before.  That is why you don't see any zeros.  They were *overwritten*.

Comment: @wyverniv, moreover, the (integer) zeros with which the array is initialized indeed do not correspond to the character `'0'`.  They are rather the same as `'\0'` -- that is, the character used as a string terminator.

Comment: Oh okay, so that means that if I try to print out each element of a character array, I won't be able to see any of the zeros because the convention is that C arrays are null-terminated with the \0 character. Thanks guys!